# Django TypeError Field 'id' expected a number but got <class 'account.models.User'>

Tags: python, django, object

Error: `TypeError: Field 'id' expected a number but got <class 'account.models.User'>.`

I have been reading the authentication documentation and I keep getting that error. I have tried a few different permutations of this but I'm really not sure what is going wrong other than its obviously a type error.

The end goal is to just return the 'id' and 'email' of the newly created user, along with the token, I haven't been able to test the token returning yet, because of this error, but I imagine it should be good.

What is working though is it is successfully posting a new user to the database with a token in another table with a matching key and now I have about 50 users from just testing and messing around.

Side note I have overridden the default User Django sets you up with, but I followed the documentation so that code should be solid, but if need I can obviously post it

Views.py

```
from rest_framework import status
from .models import User
from .serializers import UserSerializer, RegisterSerializer
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token



@api_view(['POST',])
def RegisterAPI(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = RegisterSerializer(data = request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
        user = serializer.save()
        content = {
            'user': {'id': user.pk, 'email': user.email},
            'auth': Token.objects.get(user = User).key 
        }
        # Return the reponse
        return Response(content)`
```

Serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
from .models import User

# Register Serializer
class RegisterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta: 
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'email', 'password')
        extra_kwargs = {'password':{'write_only': True}}

    def save(self):
        user = User(
            email = self.validated_data['email'],
        )
        password = self.validated_data['password']

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user

# User Serializer
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email')
```

[Documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/)

[Similar article that didn't help me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60898397/field-id-expected-a-number-but-got-built-in-function-id)

Comment: In this line, `Token.objects.get(user=User)`, the `User` should be replaced with ***user model instance***, currently, it is *User model "class"*

Comment: @ArakkalAbu if you write some code below ill mark that as correct, and thank you that worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the **`User` model class** to the **`.get(...)`** method, but it should be the ***`User` model instance*** which is just got from the serializer.

```
@api_view(['POST', ])
def register_api(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = RegisterSerializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.save()
        content = {
            'user': {'id': user.pk, 'email': user.email},
            'auth': Token.objects.get(user=user).key
        }
        # Return the reponse
        return Response(content)
```