# Field 'id' expected a number but got <built-in function id> error

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I want to add a favorites button in my template but seem to run into this error.

[image]

**Views.py**

```
class PropertyDetailSlugView(DetailView):
queryset = Property.objects.all()

template_name = "property/property_details.html"

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    slug = self.kwargs.get('slug')
    obj = self.get_object()
    tags = obj.tag_set.all()

    if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
        for tag in tags:
            new_view = TagView.objects.add_count(self.request.user, tag)

    featured = list(Property.objects.filter(featured=True))
    property_type = Category.objects.all()
    property_list = list(Property.objects.all())
    city = City.objects.all().annotate(
        num_property=Count("property")).order_by("-num_property")
   
    favorite_property = get_object_or_404(Property, id=id)

    is_favorite = False

    if favorite_property.favorite.filter(id=self.request.user.id).exists():
        is_favorite = True
        
    context['featured'] = featured
    context['is_favorite'] = is_favorite
    context['property_type'] = property_type
    context['property_list'] = property_list
    context['city'] = city
    return context
```

**Urls.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.urls import path, re_path
from .import views

from .views import (

    PropertyDetailSlugView,
)

app_name = 'property'

urlpatterns = [

    path('<slug:slug>/', login_required(PropertyDetailSlugView.as_view()), name='details'),
    path('<int:id>/favorite_property/', views.favoriteProperty, name='favorite_property'),
]
```

The error seems to occur while using the Id in Class Based Views is there a different way of using the Id's while using CBV. Any insight would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Field 'id' expected a number but got <built-in function id>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60898397/field-id-expected-a-number-but-got-built-in-function-id)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not use `id`, since that is the [builtin `id` function [Python-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id), you use `self.kwargs['id']` to retrieve the `id` parameter from the `urls.py`:

```
favorite_property = get_object_or_404(Property, id=self.kwargs['id'])
```

Comment: Tried the above solution and it is throwing a new error.  `Exception Value: 'id'`

Comment: @JosphatGitogo: yes, that's because the url has uses a slug, so then you filter with `get_object_or_404(Property, slug=self.kwargs['slug'])`

Answer (score 0):

If in `Property` class there are a field `slug` then filter it by using :-

```
favorite_property = get_object_or_404(Property, slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
```

Or, if there are no `slug` field in class `Property` then So, give it a try:-

```
favorite_property = get_object_or_404(Property, id=self.kwargs['id'])
```